# Stoping all threads in ThreadPool if an exception occurs

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I need to stop executing threads in a `ThreadPool` in case any of them throws an Exception.
My solution is one by referencing the `ExecutorService` on each `Runnable` and calling `shutdownNow()` on it. Not sure if this is OK. The actual code is more complex as it involves email sending as a task but I simplified for illustration:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Concurrency {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            exec.execute(new Tasku(exec));
        }
    }

    public static class Tasku implements Runnable {
        ExecutorService executorService;

        public Tasku(ExecutorService executorService) {
            this.executorService = executorService;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());
                if (counter.intValue() == 10) {
                    try {
                        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        executorService.shutdownNow();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above example works, after the 10th increment of counter it stops. Console output:

```
1
4
6
7
5
9
3
2
10
8
```

Is this a good way of handling the scenario? If not, how?

Thanks

Comment: why are you throwing and then catching the same exception.  Why not just call `shutdownNow()` directly?

Comment: Simulating an Exception, it can be shutdownNow() only in this example but in the real code an exception is expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is a reasonable solution. You can improve it by overriding Executor.exec(Runnable r) and submitting new Tasku(r) instead of r. This way Executor's interface remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand your improvement suggestion, can you elaborate with code?